# How to use the LIMIT argument in an SQLite Query with Android

Tags: android, sql, limit

I am trying to use the following query to get the most recent result by date.

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_DATE, KEY_REPS, 
KEY_WEIGHT}, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE + "DESC", ???);
```

I need to use the limit argument (I believe) but it takes a string.  I tried creating a string with a value of "1" but that didn't work.  Other things I tried
"1"
LIMIT 1
"LIMIT 1"
Limit 1
"Limit 1"

Also, if anyone knows of a great reference site (other than this one) that actually shows you various SQL queries (for ANDROID) that would be very helpful...

EDIT
The error I got from using "1"...perhaps the limit isn't my problem?
Here is the error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: dateDESC: , while compiling: SELECT date, repetitions, weight, FROM TEST ORDER BY dateDESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Your error was that you had `KEY_DATE + "DESC"` instead of `KEY_DATE + " DESC"`, i.e. you were missing a space.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`Order by id DESC Limit 1`:

```
db.query("table", null, "column=?", new String[]{"value"}, null, null, "id DESC", "1");
```

Comment: DESC means the order type...Z-A type

Comment: Right, I know that.  That's why I have it in my code.  So it sorts it with the highest date at the top.  Are you telling me that the DESC statement that I have in my code already is wrong?

Comment: try this: Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_DATE, KEY_REPS, 
KEY_WEIGHT}, null, null, null, null, KEY_DATE + " DESC", "1");

You miss a space before DESC

Comment: Yep, just figured that out myself.  Thanks.

Comment: what if there is offset?  0 or 1 based?