# LIMIT and OFFSET is not working properly in android

Tags: java, android, database

My Database table:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3
First Col   Second Col  Third Col
First Row   First Row   First Row
Second Row  Second Row  Second Row
Third Row   Third Row   Third Row
Four Row    Four Row    Four Row
Fifth Row   Fifth Row   Fifth Row
```

I am trying below queries:

First Query:

```
String q = "select * from " + tableName + " LIMIT 2 OFFSET 3 ";
 sqlDB.rawQuery(q,null);
```

Second Query:

```
sqlDB.query(q, null,null, null, null, null, null, "3,2");
```

Both the queries giving me below result:

```
First Col   Second Col  Third Col
First Col   Second Col  Third Col
```

Instead of below result:

```
Third Row   Third Row   Third Row
Four Row    Four Row    Four Row
```

Am i missing something or doing wrong? to get this result.

Comment: `sqlDB.query(q, null,null, null, null, null, null, "2,3")` should be giving 3, not 2, records AFAIK.

Comment: As a side note: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, you are right. i changed the query.

Comment: When you use the shortcut way like `x,y` it is interpreted as `OFFSET,LIMIT`. I find it a non intuitive design.

Comment: @Enzokie Actually, it might more intutive, in the sense that it says "jump a certain number of records down" and then "take a certain number of records for the result set."

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 3
```

means return two records, starting in the *fourth* position.

Your API call to SQLite's Android DB query

```
sqlDB.query(q, null,null, null, null, null, null, "3,2");
```

has a limit string of `"3,2"`, which is in the format

```
"offset, limit"
```

In other words, the offset and limit switch positions, and therefore the queries are saying the same thing, and hence you get the same result sets.

FYI, I found nothing in the documentation about this, but I did find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690281/limiting-a-sqlite-query-in-android) which mentions the syntax for the limit string in SQLite's Android API.

**Update:**

In order to get consistent behavior while using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, either in a native query or using the Android API, it probably makes sense to also use `ORDER BY`.  Using an ordering on the result set allows an offset or a limit to make sense with regard to your underlying data.  Database tables themselves are modeled after unordered sets.  So using offset without `ORDER BY` most likely isn't what you want to be doing.

Comment: I tried this query:

String q = "select * from  tableName  ORDER BY  Column2  LIMIT 2 OFFSET 3 ";  
but it is still giving me same result.