# Window is full! Retrieving bitmap from SQLite database

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap, blob

I am trying to store and retrieve the image captured by device camera in `SQLite Database` as `BLOB` . I have no problem to do it, but when I retrieve images from DB I get an error, because of cursor, right?

> W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 707903 bytes, free space 680839 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes

After long time looking for solution I couldn't find it. I found only a lot of questions about the same issue without solid solution.

I can store  `URI` of image , like it is discussed [Android: Cursor Window is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863024/android-cursor-window-is-full). But then what happens if user deletes the image from Phone Memory/SD Card?

Also its not a good idea to ignore it, answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37035510/8258166.

So, what should I do?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "I am trying to store and retreave the image captured by device camera in SQLite Database as BLOB" -- I do not recommend this. "But then what happens if user deletes the image from Phone Memory/SD Card?" -- store the image on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), where the user does not have direct access to the image.

Comment: Cool! 3 day headache is gone! Chears @CommonsWare